# Unable to inject Entity Repository into service

Tags: dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm currently setting up an application with Symfony 3 and Doctrine 2.5 and I'm trying to inject an entity repository into a service and I keep getting the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to UserService::setUserRepository() must
>   be an instance of UserRepository, instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given, called in
>   appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 373

This is how wire things up in my `services.yml`:

```
service_user:
  class: UserService
  calls:
    - [setUserRepository, ["@service_user_repository"]]

service_user_repository:
  class: UserRepository
  factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
  arguments: [Entity\User]
```

This is my `UserService`:

```
<?php

class UserService {

    protected $userRepository;

    public function setUserRepository( UserRepository $userRepository )
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

}
```

And this is my `UserRepository`:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {

}
```

I have checked and double checked my namespaces and class names, all seem to check out fine.

How do I inject an entity repository into a service with Symfony 3 service wiring?

Comment: Have you set `UserRepository` as repository of `Entity\User` entity in its mapping?

Comment: @dragoste Thank you! That line was commented out in my yml definition... I think I better delete this question? Unless you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I've posted an answer because I think it's a common issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, everything you've showed looks fine.

But since you're getting from entity manager an `EntityRepository` instance instead of `UserRepository`, it means that you didn't configured `User` entity to have custom (`UserRepository`) repository class.

If you use YAML mapping, it should be something like:

```yaml
Entity\User:
    repositoryClass: UserRepository
    # rest of mapping
```